# How many times does a number fit in value

Tags: php, for-loop, math

I try to create an array, with the following results:

```
$array = array(0, 100, 200, 245);
```

I have a variable, with the max value from the array: `$TotalResults` (245)

How do I create a sum, that does $TotalResults - 100, and put the result like an array in the example above?

Comment: Question is unclear.Please specify a bit more with your expected outcome along with what you have tried so for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $array = array(0, 100, 200, 245);
$TotalResult = max($array);
$TotalResult1 = $TotalResult - 100;
$array[] = $TotalResult1;
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 100 [2] => 200 [3] => 245 [4] => 145 )
```

Comment: Assuming you meant the $TotalResult is the sum of all your elements in your array.

Comment: I have edited to produce the max value from $array. If by any chance @Ruub meant sum of the array for the $TotalResults then change `$TotalResult = max($array);` to `$TotalResults = array_sum($array);`

Comment: Thanks for the help :)